# Message: Class 'CI_Form_validation' not found .codeigniter 3.

Tags: forms, validation, codeigniter-3

im working on one project with codeigniter 3
i want to use a extended [form_validation](https://github.com/Patroklo/codeigniter3.x-extended-rules), i copied language file to my language folder and library file to application/libraries and also i added my_form_validation to config/autoload.php libraries

but when i want to run page i get this error

Fatal error: Class 'CI_Form_validation' not found in /admin/application/libraries/MY_Form_Validation.php on line 76
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Class 'CI_Form_validation' not found

Filename: libraries/MY_Form_Validation.php

Line Number: 76

Backtrace:

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by adding for_validation to autoload.php->libraries and adding $this->load->library('my_form_validation'); to my php file

but now i have another issue that, file upload rule not work for me

$FormRules = array(
            array(
                'field' => 'txtName',
                'label' => 'test4',
                //'rules' => 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[100]'
                'rules'=>'required|callback__custom_check_length[5,100]'
            ),array(
                'field' => 'cmb_article_category_list',
                'label' => 'test3',
                'rules'=>'required|callback__custom_check_empty_dropdown'
            ),array(
                'field' => 'fileImage',
                'label' => 'test1',
                'rules'=>'file_allowed_type[image]'
            )
            ,array(
                'field' => 'txtDescription',
                'label' => 'test',
                'rules'=>'required|callback__custom_check_length[5,300]'
            )
        );
        $this->form_validation->set_rules($FormRules);

all rules work but file upload rule do not work

Answer (score 0):

You can add  form_validation to \CodeIgniter\application\config\autoload.php  find libraries and adding `$autoload['libraries'] = array('form_validation');`

or add  `$this->load->library('form_validation');` in construct: in controller